# Fator de Cotação

Tags: sql, sql-server

A SQL abaixo me retorna valor das cotações, eu preciso encontrar fator dia da cotação que se resume assim:
SQL

```
SELECT SIMBOLO,
       CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),DATA,103) as DATA,
       FATOR 
FROM GCOTACAO  
WHERE SIMBOLO = 'CDI'


Símbolo     Data         Fator    Fator Dia
CDI         01/01/2014   10084    = fator - 1 = 0,0084
CDI         01/02/2014   10163    = Fator (10163 - 10084) - 1 
CDI         01/03/2014   10240    = Fator (10240 - 10163) - 1
```

Agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Answer (score 1):

Ronnie Von, experimente o seguinte código sql:

```
SELECT SIMBOLO as [Símbolo], 
       convert (char(10), DATA, 103) as Data,
       FATOR as Fator,
       [Fator dia]= (FATOR - coalesce (lag (FATOR) over (order by DATA), 10000)) / 10000.
  from GCOTACAO;
```

Ele faz uso da função [LAG()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sqlallproducts-allversions) para obter o valor de FATOR da linha anterior.

Comment: Mestre Jose Diz, era isso mesmo, muito obrigado